# Как называется иностранное слово, адаптированное под местный язык?

Tags: лингвистика

Как называется иностранное слово, адаптированное под местный язык?

Например: "Автомобил**Ь**", "телевизор", "тради**ЦИЯ**", "револ**ЮЦИЯ**...

Один у нас говорит, мол, это называется калька, а второй - транслитерация. А вот я считаю, что ни так и ни эдак. Но как именно - сам не знаю. :) Просто я знаю, что такое калька и транслитерация и что оба не подходят для данного случая.

Прошу Вас, помогите узнать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие слова называются **заимствование**. Так как все заимствованные слова спустя короткое время адаптируются под язык-реципиент, то вводить для этого явления отдельный термин не имеет смысла.

*Калька, транслитерация, транскрипция* - это методы заимствования, любой из которых ведет к тому или иному искажению языка-оригинала.

Comment: Премного благодарен. Спасибо.
Ответ считаю несколько огорчительным - не удалось оставить свой след в филологии!(с) - но исчерпывающим, и потому поступаю в соответствии установленными правилами.

Answer (score 1):

Как такового термина, называющего адаптированное заимствованное слово, вряд ли существует. Калька, транслитерация, транскрипция - не являются как таковыми названиями этих слов, это метод заимствования. 
Приведенные вами примеры - заимствованы при помощи транскрипции. 
Исключение составляет слово "телевизор". Здесь часть слова ***"теле"*** взята из языка источника, а ***видение(vision)*** переведено при помощи кальки. Некоторые лингвисты называют такой способ ***полукалькой.***

> Полукальки - это слова, в которых есть и заимствованные и русские части: гуманность, иноязычный, телевидение, спикерщина, албанщина.

Comment: Тогда выходит надо восполнить этот пробел, согласитесь?! Ведь как ни крути, а получается, что явление само де факто есть, а вот термина своего не имеет. И если всё обстоит именно так, тогда давайте совместно придумаем название термину, и тем самым внесём свою скромную лепту в развитие науки, коим является также и филология.

Господа филологи, вы не против этого предложения? (Разумеется, при условии действительного отсутствия такого термина)

Comment: У меня даже варианты названия термину появились. Ну, назовём этот термин, скажем, *ТРАНСФОРМАЦИЕЙ*. А можно и *ТРАНСМУТАЦИЕЙ*

Comment: Термин "трансформация" уже существует, а трансмутация - не подойдет. Согласитесь, не те ассоциации. Раз термина до сих пор не существует, значит, в нем нет потребности.

Comment: "Раз термина до сих пор не существует, значит, в нем нет потребности."
===========================
Улыбнуло. Чистейший софизм, должен заметить.